# Swap operation in a Radiative Random Unitary Circuit

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-information, phase-transition, open-quantum-systems

In ref [PhysRevLett.131.220404](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.131.220404), the author have studied the scrambling in a Radiative Random Unitary Circuit (RUC) -- a RUC that exchanges qubits with an environment at a rate $p$.

It might perhaps be trivial, but the author did not mention how does the swapping operation is performed except

> *Between layers of unitary gates, each system qubit is swapped with an environment ancilla qubit with probability $p$; crucially, we use a fresh ancilla qubit for each such interaction, and we do not trace out the ancilla following the system-ancilla interaction.*

This suggests that if the circuit has $N$ qubits then there should be associated $N$ ancilla qubits for each qubit. What do they mean by *we use a fresh ancilla qubit for each such interaction*?

Further, they defined the OTOC as

$$C(t) = \frac{1}{4} \text{tr}\left\{ \rho^\text{SE} \left[X_0(t),Y_x\right]^\dagger \left[X_0(t), Y_x\right] \right\}$$
where $\rho^{\text{SE}}$ is initial state on the system $S$ and environment $E$. How does the operator dimensions are matched in definition of the OTOC? Since $X_0(t)= U^\dagger_tX_0U$ is defined on system.

Comment: "Fresh ancilla" = "ancilla initialized in a well-known state"

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Does each qubit in the RUC have an associated ancilla qubit? If so, the state will have the form $|\psi(t)\rangle  = \sum_{xp} c_{xp} |x\rangle |p\rangle ^{\otimes N}$. Then, how do you initialize ancilla qubits in this state?

Comment: Yeah, there are *at least as many* ancilla qubits as physical ones. There can be extra unused qubits. Ancilla qubits are initialized in some state, let's say the +1 eigenstate of Pauli $Z$. Resetting a qubit to this state is a standard operation in quantum hardware. You can do this by measuring $Z$ and applying $X$ if you get $-1$. As a separate comment, the idea that this information can be decoded / unscrambled is preposterous. It's like sending QI into a black hole and then unitarily evolving it back out. It's unphysical nonsense.

Comment: I am also little confused with the definition of OTOC. Does that take into account the ancilla qubit? In other words, does the operator $X_0(t)$ contains ancilla qubit?